# Htaccess redirect all to index.php not working if param starts http:// or www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I’m using that `.htaccess` to `redirect` all after slash to my `index.php` param :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But then im trying to go `mysite.co/http://someurl.co` or `mysite.co/http://www.someurl.co` (`mysite.co/www.someurl.co` redirecting well) im getting error

> You don't have permission to access mysite.co/http://www.someurl.co on
>   this server.

Comment: `mysite.co/http://someurl.co` does not seem to be a proper URL.

Comment: thats why i want to redirect it to `index.php?q=$1` i just want to give ability to paste any `url` after slash of my webpage

Comment: no it does. Any ideas how to pass `http://www` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` engine strips all double slashes to single ones in `RewriteRule` so you cannot match `http://www` in `RewriteRule`. Use `RewriteCond` instead with `THE_REQUEST` parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S+)
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?q=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks but im getting `was not found on this server.` still

Comment: Try updated code, also tell me what exact URL did you use to test

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unclear. What are you trying to do? This is the standard WordPress `.htaccess` which appears close to what you are attempting. Perhaps using that would work better:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Im trying to pass all my `url` to `?q=` all works fine except when i'm trying to pass `http://` or `http://www` after slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^http\:\/+.*$ index.php?q=$0 [L,QSA]
```